# Angular 5 - Error Metadata version mismatch for module

Tags: angular

While trying to build my angular 5 project incurred the following error. My version is 5.6.0, and @angular/material@5.0.1.

> C:\Users\Owner\ng7>ng build --prod Date: 2017-12-18T02:42:21.623Z
>   Hash: 2c0633800516bc024772 Time: 16640ms chunk {0}
>   styles.f7ba5027ddae0481d607.bundle.css (styles) 290 bytes {3}
>   [initial] [rendered] chunk {1}
>   polyfills.3bc34265385d52184eab.bundle.js (polyfills) 86 bytes {3}
>   [initial] [rendered] chunk {2} main.e402deade8b026b7d50e.bundle.js
>   (main) 84 bytes [initial] [rendered] chunk {3}
>   inline.9d07561b59257af76b95.bundle.js (inline) 1.45 kB [entry]
>   [rendered]
>
> ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module
>   C:/Users/Owner/ng7/node_modules/@angular/animations/animations.d.ts,
>   found version 4, expected 3
>       at StaticSymbolResolver.getModuleMetadata (C:\Users\Owner\ng7\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:25616:34)
>       at StaticSymbolResolver._createSymbolsOf (C:\Users\Owner\ng7\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:25404:46)
>       at StaticSymbolResolver.getSymbolsOf (C:\Users\Owner\ng7\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:25385:14)
>       at C:\Users\Owner\ng7\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24241:30
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at extractProgramSymbols (C:\Users\Owner\ng7\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24240:79)
>       at AotCompiler.analyzeModulesAsync (C:\Users\Owner\ng7\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23796:47)
>       at CodeGenerator.codegen (C:\Users\Owner\ng7\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:32:14)
>       at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.codeGen (C:\Users\Owner\ng7\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:73:30)
>       at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then (C:\Users\Owner\ng7\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:386:44)
>       at

Answer (score 0):

in your angular project package.json file have a look at the @angular/animations module and make sure you are using the @angular/animations version which is angular 5 compliant.

from the error logs you have shared

```
ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module C:/Users/Owner/ng7/node_modules/@angular/animations/animations.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3 at StaticSymbolResolver.getModuleMetadata
```

I can conclude that you are still on angular 4 and not angular 5. request you to update all your dependencies i package.json to angular 5 in your case specifically angular animation module.